# Skewed button not changing text color on hover properly

Tags: css

So I got this transition effect, and everything works fine but when the cursor is at the edges of this button(when I hover over the skewed edges), button does not change the text color to white. It works well only when I hover closer to the middle. Is there a way to fix it, what am I missing here..? Thank you.

Here's the codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dvPJvx

```
.skew-button {
      border: 1px solid red;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #FFF;
    transform: skew(-20deg);
}

.skew-button a {
    position: relative;
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    z-index: 10;
    transform: skew(20deg);
    color: black;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    padding: 10px 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: all .2s linear;
}

.skew-button a:hover {
  color: #FFF;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.skew-button:after {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 0;
    color: #fff;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
    opacity: 0;  
    transition: all .2s linear;
}

.skew-button:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
}

<button class="skew-button">
  <a href="#">Button</a>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change Line 23 to:

`.skew-button:hover a`